# Array size different from what is entered - C

Tags: c, arrays

I am compiling a code in which I can separate digits from a number given by a user and with each digit being entered into a new array.

I am new to C and I am struggling with putting the digits into the array, I have tried to print everything that is calculated so as to see where I am going wrong but I can figure it out

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int input,COUNT=0,i;



    printf("LCD calculator display.\n");
    printf("Enter input:");
    scanf("%d",&input);


    int inputCopy = input;
    while(input!= 0)
    {
    input /= 10;
    COUNT++;
    printf("Count = %d\n",COUNT);
    } 

    int s = COUNT;
    int output[5];
    int SIZE = sizeof(output);
    printf("s = %d\n",s);
    printf("output size = %zu\n",sizeof(output));
    printf("Size = %d\n",SIZE);

    for(i=0;i<COUNT;i++)
    {
        int digit = inputCopy % 10;
        output[i] = digit;
        inputCopy /= 10;
        i++;
    }

    for(i=0;i<COUNT;i++)
    {
        printf("Numbers: %d\n",output[i]);
    }
}
```

I get the following results:

```
LCD calculator display.
Enter input:13579
Count = 1
Count = 2
Count = 3
Count = 4
Count = 5
s = 5
output size = 20
Size = 20
Numbers: 9
Numbers: 0
Numbers: 7
Numbers: 0
Numbers: 5
```

I know there are some unnecessary lines here they were there to help me try and figure out where I was going wrong.
Any help in getting the digits stored correctly much appreciated

Comment: You're incrementing `i` twice in your second-last `for`

Comment: Thanks tkausl something so simple and it fixed it

Comment: You do realize that `sizeof()` reports the size in bytes.  That's why you get 20 printed for an array of 5 `int`, each of which is of size 4.

Answer (score 0):

Your incrementing i two times in your for loop as

```
for(i=0;i<COUNT;i++)                     // HERE
{
    int digit = inputCopy % 10;
    output[i] = digit;
    inputCopy /= 10;
    i++;                                 // AND HERE 
}
```